# How do I get just the time from an NSDate object?

Tags: swift, nsdate, swift3

Say for example my `Date` (formerly `NSDate`) object was created as the 12 June 2016 at 14:23, how would I extract just that 14:23 from my `Date` object? Basically some thing like `mydate.time`.

Comment: Your link is helpful however it isn't in Swift 3. `.CalendarUnitHour` and `.CalendarUnitMinute` are not accepted anymore.

Comment: Your post is tagged as just Swift, not Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a handy extension so you use `let time = Date().time`

```
extension Date {
    var time: String {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: self)
        return "\(components.hour!):\(components.minute!)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try now, changed to support swift 3

Comment: @Callam, as of Swift 3 you don't use the `NS` prefix.

Comment: @WMios yeah my bad, fixed it

Comment: @MartinR just tested it in swift 3 playground and it works

Comment: @MartinR yes, _after_ I edited if that's what you're getting at